# Case statement in SQL Sever to identify possible duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table with some records.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
PER_ID INT,
PER_SS VARCHAR (11),
PER_MISC VARCHAR (25),
PER_CLASS VARCHAR (20),
FILE_DT DATETIME,
PER_CASE_ID INT,
PER_CODE VARCHAR (5),
CREATE_DT DATETIME,
END_DT DATETIME

)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('9801745','6385789','21 ADC 846/841(T)(1)(B)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','957800','IDA','11/12/2016 11:00 PM','11/17/2016 12:00 AM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('9801745','6385789','21 B 1325(Q)(4)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','957800','CAN','11/12/2016 11:00 PM','11/21/2016 12:00 AM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('9801745','6385789','21 B 1325(Q)(4)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','698080','QBC','11/12/2016 11:00 PM','11/21/2016 12:00 AM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('9801745','6385789','88 EEA 1326 (K)(1)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','957800','CAN','11/12/2016 12:15 PM','')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('9801745','6385789','88 EEA 1326 (K)(1)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','698080','DLC','11/12/2016 12:15 PM','')
```

I am trying to use the case statement in SQL Server to identify possible duplicate records by creating several extra fields such as result below:

```
same per id same per ss same per misc   same per class  same file date  per id  per ss  per misc    per  class  file date   per case id per code    create date end date
yes yes no  yes yes 9801745 6385789 21 ADC 846/841(T)(1)(B) NMT785989   11/11/2016  957800  IDA 11/12/2016  11/17/2016
yes yes yes yes yes 9801745 6385789 21 B 1325(Q)(4) NMT785989   11/11/2016  957800  CAN 11/12/2016  11/21/2016
yes yes yes yes yes 9801745 6385789 21 B 1325(Q)(4) NMT785989   11/11/2016  698080  QBC 11/12/2016  11/21/2016
yes yes yes yes yes 9801745 6385789 88 EEA 1326 (K)(1)  NMT785989   11/11/2016  957800  CAN 11/12/2016  
yes yes yes yes yes 9801745 6385789 88 EEA 1326 (K)(1)  NMT785989   11/11/2016  698080  DLC 11/12/2016
```

Basically, if per id column is the same, give same per id column a yes, if per ss column is the same, give same per ss a yes, and so forth. I have attempted my SQL Server code as follow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE 
WHEN A.PER_ID = B.PER_ID THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_ID,

CASE 
WHEN A.PER_SS = B.PER_SS THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_SS,

CASE 
WHEN A.PER_MISC = B.PER_MISC THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_MISC,

CASE 
WHEN A.PER_CLASS = B.PER_CLASS THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_CLASS,

CASE 
WHEN A.FILE_DT = B.FILE_DT THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_FILE_DT,
A.PER_ID, 
A.PER_SS, 
A.PER_MISC,
A.PER_CASE_ID,
A.PER_CLASS,
A.FILE_DT,
A.CREATE_DT,
A.END_DT
FROM #TEMP A INNER JOIN #TEMP B
ON A.PER_ID = B.PER_ID
ORDER BY A.PER_ID, A.PER_CASE_ID
```

However, I have 10 records returned instead of just 5 records and the result is not what I expected. Is there a way I in SQL sever that can solve the issue?

Comment: Can you share what you expect as output?

Comment: This question was rewritten into a new question after an answer below was given. I have rolled back to the original version, and then tidied that one up. Please do not substantially modify questions after an answer is provided - answers should flow from questions for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want to show if there are different value for a per_id in different rows for a set of columns. You can use window function `MIN` and `MAX` to check if there are multiple different values in different column for the same per_id.

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when max(PER_SS) over (partition by per_id) = min(PER_SS) over (partition by per_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as same_per_ss,
    case when max(PER_MISC) over (partition by per_id) = min(PER_MISC) over (partition by per_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as same_per_misc,
    case when max(PER_CLASS) over (partition by per_id) = min(PER_CLASS) over (partition by per_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as same_per_class,
    case when max(FILE_DT) over (partition by per_id) = min(FILE_DT) over (partition by per_id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end as same_per_file_dt
from #temp t;
```

Comment: @ Gurwinder Singh, I have edited my sample data and explained the next issue I encounter. Thanks for your help. Joe

Comment: @Joe - Don't ask multiple questions in a single one. Please open a new question.

Comment: @Sing. will do Sir

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to do an inner join from the table to itself. Something like:

SELECT * FROM TEMP T1 INNER JOIN TEMP T2 ON T1.PER_SS = T2.PER_SS AND T1.PER_ID = T2.PER_ID -- etc.

You could also try something like this.

SELECT T1.* FROM TEMP T1, TEMP T2 WHERE T1.PER_SS = T2.PER_SS AND T1.PER_ID = T2.PER_ID -- etc.

Comment: They have an inner join in the query they posted. And your second query is just the antiquated syntax for an inner join.