# Case statement in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some sample records below.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
PER_ID INT,
PER_SS VARCHAR (11),
CHARGE_CD VARCHAR (25),
PER_CODE VARCHAR (20),
FILE_DT DATETIME,
PER_CASE_ID INT,
PER_PS VARCHAR (5),
CREATE_DT DATETIME


)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('6385789','9801745','21 B 1325(Q)(4)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','957800','IDA','11/12/2016 11:00 PM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('6385789','9801745','21 B 1325(Q)(4)','NMT785989','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','698080','QBC','11/12/2016 11:00 PM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('6388788','9801746','21 B 1325(Q)(4)','NMT785990','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','957801','CAN','11/12/2016 11:00 PM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('6388788','9801746','21 B 1326(Q)(5)','NMT785990','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','698081','ADA','11/12/2016 11:00 PM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('6385790','9858888','21 B 1326(Q)(5)','NMT785990','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','698888','ADA','11/12/2016 11:00 PM')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('6385790','9858888','21 B 1326(Q)(5)','NMT785990','11/11/2016 12:00 AM','698888','CAN','11/12/2016 11:00 PM')



    SELECT 
    --the case station with partition script was written by Gurwinder Singh.
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(PER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_ID,
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_SS) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(PER_SS) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_SS,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CHARGE_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(CHARGE_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_CHARGE_CD,
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(PER_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_CODE,
    CASE WHEN MAX(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_FILE_DT,
    PER_ID, 
    PER_SS, 
    CHARGE_CD,
    PER_CASE_ID,
    PER_PS,
    PER_CODE,
    FILE_DT
    FROM #TEMP
```

Is there a way that I can filter out two records PER_CASE_ID =(698888). Basically, I am not interested in seeing these two records returned since the PER_CASE_ID is the same. I am only interested in the result
where the PER_CASE_ID is different.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove *all* duplicates or just the ID 698888?

Comment: just the ID = 698888 for this particular small sample. I have about 500k or more records. I am not interested the result where records showing same PER_CASE_ID. Thanks Jacob.

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: Can you not add WHERE PER_CASE_ID != '698888' to the end of the query

Comment: Total nit-pick, but it's a CASE expression, not a CASE statement. :)

Comment: yes. Case expression. Understood. Joe

Comment: repost of [Case statement in SQL Sever to identify possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006761/case-statement-in-sql-sever-to-identify-possible-duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Row_Number() you can remove duplicates

```
 SELECT *
    From
    (
    SELECT 
    --the case station with partition script was written by Gurwinder Singh.
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(PER_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_ID,
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_SS) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(PER_SS) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_SS,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CHARGE_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(CHARGE_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_CHARGE_CD,
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(PER_CODE) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_CODE,
    CASE WHEN MAX(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) = MIN(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_ID) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_FILE_DT,
    PER_ID, 
    PER_SS, 
    CHARGE_CD,
    PER_CASE_ID,
    PER_PS,
    PER_CODE,
    FILE_DT
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by PER_CASE_ID Order by PER_CASE_ID) As Seq
    FROM #TEMP 
    )dt
WHERE dt.Seq=1
```

Comment: Thanks to ALL for your help! Joe

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're linked by PER_ID, then

```
SELECT ...
    FROM #TEMP t
WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT * FROM #TEMP t2 
               WHERE t2.PER_ID = t.PER_ID 
               AND t2.PER_CASE_ID <> t.PER_CASE_ID
             )
```

Comment: Thanks Gareth. PER_CASE_ID is not linked by PER_ID. Joe

Comment: No worries, the CASE statements in the select seems to suggest they were linked.

Answer (score 0):

If the PER_PS value is unimportant and you can always take the greater or less of all duplicate values for this field then you can group omitting PER_PS. However, if there will be other relationships besides PER_ID and PER_PS that yields multiple records then this solution becomes more troublesome.

```
SELECT 
    PER_ID, 
    PER_SS, 
    CHARGE_CD,
    PER_CASE_ID,
    MAX_PER_PS=MAX(PER_PS),
    MIN_PER_PS=MIN(PER_PS), 
    PER_CODE,
    FILE_DT
    FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY
    PER_ID, 
    PER_SS, 
    CHARGE_CD,
    PER_CASE_ID,
    PER_CODE,
    FILE_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with cte as (select PER_CASE_ID from #TEMP group by PER_CASE_ID having count(*) = 1)
select ... from #TEMP as src 
where exists (select * from cte where cte.PER_CASE_ID = src.PER_CASE_ID)
order by ...;
```